# Sorting on multiple fields in mongodb via mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a userModel that has about 5 fields that I would like to be sorted in Ascending or Descending when I `find({})` them. Everything I have read from the documentation suggests that this should work but it's not working.

This query only returns a correct order for the **first value** e.g `firstName` and returns a non-sorted result for the rest. These are the different sorting techniques that I've tried to implement and all return the same result. if I try to flip to **Descending** order, the exact same behaviour occurs.

```
UserModel.find({}).sort({firstName: 'asc', lastName:'asc' ,email:'asc',createdAt:'asc', updatedAt:'asc' })
UserModel.find({}).sort({firstName: 1, lastName:1 ,email:1, createdAt:1 , updatedAt: 1 })
UserModel.find({}).sort("firstName lastName email createdAt updatedAt")
UserModel.find({}).sort("firstName, lastName, email, createdAt, updatedAt")
```

UserModel

```
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    firstName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter a valid first name."],
    },
    lastName: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please enter a valid last name."],
    },
    email: {
      type: String,
      required: [true, "Please provide a valid email address."],
      unique: true
    },
    dob: {
      type: Date,
      default: null,
    },
)

export default mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model("User", UserSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need first to create an index and sort after.

```
UserModel.createIndex( {firstName: 1, lastName:1 ,email:1, createdAt:1 , updatedAt: 1 })
```

And take data from the DB after:

```
UserModel.find().sort( {firstName: 1, lastName:1 ,email:1, createdAt:1 , updatedAt: 1 } )
```

More details are at https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/sort-results-with-indexes/

Comment: interesting! Have you got any ideas on how i could sort for multiple columns?

Comment: Yes, you can do it by indexes, however, you need to add it first. I misunderstood your question initially

Comment: could you please show me how that's done? a practical example or something. Thank you!

Comment: You can see an example in the answer block

Comment: I've seen your answer and i looks great but i have 1 more question. how do i go about this in the context of mongoose? where do i call the users.createIndex method. Thanks once again

Comment: Please, attach to the question your file with UserModel.js code

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236757/discussion-between-muhammed-a-o-and-dmitrii).

Comment: its been added and also sent to the chat. whichever one is cool with you

Comment: You can use UserModel.find() then, I have updated the answer

Comment: did not get desired result :(